# How to execute delete statement inside a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want clients of my application to call `DELETE` statements indirectly or using a function. This is what I tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION layer_250_delete(layer_id integer)
    RETURNS bool AS
$BODY$ 
BEGIN    
    EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM layer_250_ WHERE id = $1' USING layer_id;    
    RETURN TRUE;   
END; 
$BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
   COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION layer_250_delete(integer)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

I also tried a raw query:

```
...
DELETE FROM layer_250_ WHERE id = 1';    
RETURN TRUE;
...
```

However, when I call this function (variant 1 or 2) like this:

```
select layer_250_delete(1);
```

it does not delete a row from `layer_250_` table. I scanned dozens of threads here at stackoverflow, but could not find anything similar to my task.

**STRUCTURE**

```
CREATE TABLE public.layer_250_
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('layer_250__id_seq'::regclass),
  feature_type character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  feature_hash character varying(500) NOT NULL,
  feature_uid character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  geom geometry,
  radius integer,
  group_id integer,
  object_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  row_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  action_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  action_type character varying(255),
  action_user_id integer,
  action_user_ip character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT layer_250__pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT layer_250__feature_uid_key UNIQUE (feature_uid),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_geom_layer_250_ CHECK (st_ndims(geom) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_geom_layer_250_ CHECK (st_srid(geom) = 3857)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.layer_250_
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: share a structure? `\d+ layer_250_ `

Comment: Please, have a look

Comment: what happens if you run `begin; explain (analyze,buffers on) DELETE FROM layer_250_ WHERE id = 1; ROLLBACK;
`?.. any exceptions?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yrs, it does:

```
  t=# create table layer_250_ (id int);
    CREATE TABLE
    t=# insert into layer_250_ select 1;
    INSERT 0 1
    t=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION layer_250_delete(layer_id integer)
    t-#     RETURNS bool AS
    t-# $BODY$
    t$# BEGIN
    t$#     EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM layer_250_ WHERE id = $1' USING layer_id;
    t$#     RETURN TRUE;
    t$# END;
    t$# $BODY$
    t-#    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    t-#    COST 100;
    CREATE FUNCTION
    t=# ALTER FUNCTION layer_250_delete(integer)
    t-# OWNER TO postgres;
    ALTER FUNCTION
    t=# begin;
    BEGIN
    t=# select layer_250_delete(1);
     layer_250_delete
    ------------------
     t
    (1 row)

    t=# select * from layer_250_;
     id
    ----
    (0 rows)

    t=# end;
    COMMIT
```

Comment: Strange as it is, but it does not work in my case. Probably, because of some config.

Comment: create a database in same cluster and run my commands on newly created db. config is shared across databases, but I'm quite sure it will work. If so, I'd check out structure, not configs. maybe you have a trigger, maybe  a rule instead of delete. dunno - many invariants